# ng-model-binding not updating when changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

[ng-repeat is used to form this table]

Want to do following tasks :

1. Step1- input in PromoPriceTxt3 text box should reflect in other text
   boxes below it too. i.e PromoPriceTxt4
2. Step2- The change in the "PromoPrice" text boxes,
       should affect the value in third column from right based on a
       formula (item.promo_margin * item.promo_price) - item.promo_price + item.gasv) > 0)

step 1 is done. but step two not working.

**I have bound them with same ng-model**. the change in value is visible in UI. but when I inspect element in chrome, i see old value in "value" property of the text box. (red marked in the inspect window)

I have also tried invoking a method, on text change. but that too just didnt work. **the change event is invoked when the  I focus the cursor in the subsequent text box and change it**.

```html
<tbody data-ng-repeat="item in prod track by $index">
    <tr>
    <td>{{item.sku}}</td>
    <td>{{item.retailer_nm}}</td>
    <td>{{item.base_margin | number : 4}}</td>
    <td bgcolor="#c0c0c0"><span data-ng-hide="item.editing" data-ng-dblclick="editItem(item)">
    {{item.promo_margin | number : 4}}</span>
    <input data-ng-show="item.editing" data-ng-model="item.promo_margin" data-ng-blur="doneEditing()" autofocus />
    </td>
    <td>{{item.gasv | number : 2}}</td>
    <td>{{item.base_dcm_per_unit | number : 2}}</td>
    <td ng-if="((item.promo_margin * item.promo_price) - item.promo_price + item.gasv) > 0">{{((item.promo_margin * item.promo_price) - item.promo_price + item.gasv) | number : 2}}</td>
    <td ng-if="((item.promo_margin * item.promo_price) - item.promo_price + item.gasv) < 0">0.00</td>
    <td>{{item.map | number : 2}}</td>
    <td ng-if="$index==0">
    <input  id="PromoPriceTxt3" data-ng-blur="setPromoPrice()"  class="maintextbox" type="text"  data-ng-model="item.promo_price"  data-ng-value="{{item.promo_price}}"/>
</td>
<td ng-if="$index!=0">
<input id="PromoPriceTxt4"  class="replicate" type="text" data-ng-model="item.promo_price" onfocus="" data-ng-value="{{item.promo_price}}"
/>
</td></tr></tbody>
```

Comment: Yes, Momin. This was first time I was posting a query

Answer (score 0):

can u try `$scope.$apply()` function .. cause it worked for me  most of the times

Answer (score 0):

Make use of ng-change directive. Refer the link https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-change.asp

Comment: I invoked a method using this event. still didnt work

Comment: It can actually be as simple as how two way data binding happens
<input type='text' ng-model="data">
{{data}}
Just make sure you refer to the right ng-model